# .Net - Find all Networked Computer names and their shared folders

Tags: vb.net, networking, .net

I'm wanting to find all the names of the computers that are currently on the same network. Once I have the names, I want to see if a shared directory named `Shared\NetworkFiles` exists. *Edited and added - I might not know the actual network name itself to scan all the computers under a specific network name.

For instance: one working path is `\\EQIZLOCAL-PC\Shared\NetworkFiles`

I may have several other computers on the network as well that I'm not 100% sure what their names are that may have the same directory that exists and I need to be able to return a list of computer names that do have that path available.

Long story short... I just need to be able to

1. get all the names of the computers on the network
2. while getting the names check to see if the folder paths actually exist and add them to a listbox or something and i can handle the rest.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently, you can use **Imports System.DirectoryServices**

There's example code on [VB.NET List all Computers in Network/Workgroup](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/87499508-63f3-40ec-a82e-14a6da3f3bed/vbnet-list-all-computers-in-networkworkgroup-)

That should answer at least part of your question.